# Python3 - Doc2Vec: Get document by vector/ID

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I've already built my Doc2Vec model, using around 20.000 files. I'm looking for a way to find the string representation of a given vector/ID, which might be similar to Word2Vec's index2entity. I'm able to get the vector itself, using model['n'], but now I'm wondering whether there's a way to get some sort of string representation of it as well.

Comment: You probaby should give some code examples, what you expect to have and what you get.

Comment: Well, I'll try. What I would want to do is give the input of a vector (or the doc's ID):

`[0.664, -0.3, 2.0]`

And I want the output to be something like: **the cat is here**. I've been looking through the [https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html](documentation), but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look up your actual training text, for a given text+tag that was part of training, you should retain that mapping outside the `Doc2Vec` model. (The model doesn't store training texts – only looking at them, repeatedly, during training.)

If you want to *generate* a text from a `Doc2Vec` doc-vector, that's not an existing feature, nor do I know any published work describing a reliable technique for doing so.

There's a speculative/experimental bit of work-in-progress for gensim `Doc2Vec` that will forward-propagate a doc-vector through the model's neural-network, and report back the most-highly-predicted target words. (This is somewhat the opposite of the way `infer_vector()` works.)

That *might*, plausibly, give a sort-of summary text. For more details see this open issue & the attached PR-in-progress:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2459

Whether this is truly useful or likely to become part of gensim is still unclear.

However, note that such a set-of-words *wouldn't* be grammatical. (It'll just be the ranked-list of most-predicted words. Perhaps some other subsystem could try to string those words together in a natural, grammatical way.)

Also, the subtleties of whether a concept has many potential associates words, or just one, could greatly affect the "top N" results of such a process. Contriving a possible example: there are many words for describing a 'cold' environment. As a result, a doc-vector for a text about something cold might have lots of near-synonyms for 'cold' in the 11th-20th ranked positions – such that the "total likelihood" of at least one cold-ish word is very high, maybe higher than any one other word. But just looking at the top-10 most-predicted words might instead list other "purer" words whose likelihood isn't so divided, and miss the (more-important-overall) sense of "coldness". So, this experimental pseudo-summarization method might benefit from a second-pass that somehow "coalesces" groups-of-related-words into their most-representative words, until some overall proportion (rather than fixed top-N) of the doc-vector's predicted-words are communicated. (This process might be vaguely like finding a set of M words whose "Word Mover's Distance" to the full set of predicted-words is minimized – though that could be a very expensive search.)

Comment: Thank you very much, gojomo. I'll definitely try what you describe as the oppsite of `infer_vector()`, as I don't think I need the texts to be grammatical as of now; otherwise I'll map it myself. Thanks a lot!